# How to use RTCM data from NTRIP caster to correct my GPS position?

Tags: gps, ntrip, real-time-kinematic

I have written a code which performs a connection to a NTRIP caster and receives data in RTCM3 format.

I have been able to decode these messages and I can distinguish them in base to their code such as (1006, 1008, 1013, etc..).

But I don't know which of this data I have to use to correct my GPS position and how to perform this correction.

Could you give me some hints or references?

Answer (score 1):

1. Always mentioned which module you're using, what are the hardware interfaces.
2. I don't think you need to decode the data coming from the NTRIP server. Most of the time the RTK module does that on his own, all you have to do is redirect the data coming from the NTRIP server to the RTK module (without changing anything).